# jquery php and csv exporting

Tags: php, jquery, csv

I have a script for exporting results of a mysql query as a csv file. The thing is that i use jquery to access the script. I need to know how i can return the data (already in csv format) with jquery. In other words, just to make myself clear because my english is a bit poor, when the user presses a button in the html file, a post request is sent to a php file which returns the data in csv format. I want to take that data with jquery and serve the .csv file to the user.

PHP file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header ("Content-type: application/csv\nContent-Disposition: \"inline; filename=my.csv\"");
    include("config.php");
    $query = $_SESSION['sqlQuery'];

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
    echo "ID,STATUS,CATEGORY,TITLE,DATE,URL\r\n"; //header
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "$row[0],$row[4],$row[3],$row[1],$row[2]\r\n"; //data
    }
?>
```

I need something in the HTML like:

```
$("#exportToCsv").click(function(){
   $.post("export.php",function(data){
        here the code for exporting much like downloading a file
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just link to the file (no ajax, no `$.post`) with the header henchman said. It will download the file. Ajax is ment for javascript to get the file, not to perfom download.

Answer (score 0):

for which part of this task do you need help?

The following command prints a file to the user:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

eg:

```
echo file_get_contents("myfile.csv");
```

**edit**

Try to add the following headers to your php-page, which will be called for your ajax call:

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"export.csv\"");
```

Comment: <?php
session_start();
header ("Content-type: application/csv\nContent-Disposition: \"inline; filename=yourfilename.csv\"");
include("config.php");
$query = $_SESSION['sqlQuery'];

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
echo "ID,STATUS,CATEGORY,TITLE,DATE,URL\r\n"; //header
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "$row[0],$row[4],$row[3],$row[1],$row[2]\r\n"; //data
}
?>

this is the php. So i need something in the html file like:
$.post("exportCsv.php",function(data){
    something here to export as a csv file (like to download the .csv file)
});